# Subset a list from a XmlNodeList in R

Tags: r

I have a list parsed from xml by using `read_xml` in R, it produced following
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYd2d.png)

I want to subset those inputs into different dataframes assigned as `input1, input2, input3 etc`.

I tested structure of the list using `str()`

It produced

```
 $ node:<externalptr> 
 $ doc :<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

I used `df[[1]]`, it doesn't seem work in this case.

I don't know how to do it more efficiently. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue.

First of all, this is a `XmlNodeList` as `list[[1]]` won't work at this case.

A XML file/url needs to be parsed by using  `xml_df <- read_xml(url, encoding = "UTF-8")` first.

Then using `library(XML)` to load `XML`

According to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/vignettes/modification.html

I have found that following scripts work in my case:

`grandchildren<-xml_children(xml_children(xml_children(xml_children(xml_df)[[1]])[[1]])[8])`

Hence,

`grandchildren` can be used as a normal list.

```
> grandchildren[[1]]
{xml_node}
<input>
[1] <name>Signal</name>
[2] <id>1062011</id>
[3] <scadaTagID/>
[4] <logInterval xsi:nil="true"/>
[5] <unit/>
[6] <opdata:records>\n  <opdata:record>\n    <value>19</value>\n    <date>2021-05-17T11:14:53</date>\n  </opdata:recor ...
```

Hope it helps for others who have same issue(s).